# RASA X running issue: Make sure to start Rasa X with valid data and valid domain and config files

Tags: chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4bhY.png) I am trying to installing **Rasa**. I run this command **rasa init**. It's working fine. But when I am trying to run this command **rasa x** it throws an error as shown in the above image(link).  One solution I have found is to remove **domain_path=domain_path** from the **x.py** file which can be found in such a path: **C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\Myenv\Lib\site-packages\rasa\cli\x.py** . Even though the other solution I've heard is to downgrade the version of Python and pip. Versions are (Rasa Version: 2.8.1, Python Version:3.7, pip version: 20.2) But still, I can't get rid of it. If anybody has a solution, please help.

Answer (score 1):

**To solve this issue, please follow the below steps:**

pip install rasa==2.8.1

check rasa --version

then install

pip install rasa-sdk==2.8.1

Install this version rasa-x==0.39.3

pip install rasa-x==0.39.3 --extra-index-url https://pypi.rasa.com/simple

Some know errors:

ImportError: cannot import name ‘RowProxy’ from ‘sqlalchemy.engine’ try running pip install SQLAlchemy==1.3.22 should fix it.)

And, if you get an error not being able to import yaml then run pip install pyyaml.